# sys.stdout.write() deal with two line

Tags: python

By using this code:

```
i=0
while i<10:
    sys.stdout.write('\r'+str(i))
    sys.stdout.flush()
    i +=1
    time.sleep(1)
```

we can count 0 to 9 in one line.
My question is that how if I wanna do this counting in two line?

I want something like counting 0-10 to a-z. For example, the first loop is to count 1-10 of a, then second is to count 1-10 of b.........
The final round is to count 1-10 of z

Output like this

First loop:

```
    a
     1-10 # here is counting 1-10
```

Second loop:

```
    b
     1-10 # here is counting 1-10
```

It means that I should print the english letter first then print 1-10
but How do I shift backward to change the english letter?

Comment: some terminals let you clear full screen and then you can write all again but you have to use external command ie. `clr` or `clear`. Or see module like `ncurses` or [urwid](http://urwid.org/)

Comment: if i have other calculation before that, will these clear function cleaning my result too.  As the reason I wanna print it like that is to understand which stage my program in

Comment: terminals don't have function/code to go to previous line. Some modules print first to buffer and then they clear screen and print everything from buffer. If you have to change something on screen they make changes in buffer, clear screen and print everything from buffer again. Check ncurses or urwid.